# Why am I unable to pass this value from this method to this other method in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

This method is of a counter and the if statements have a value I want to pass to another method. The value is called *stageTime*

```
      private void startTimer() {
        Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "CHECK","Entered startTimer() method");
        millisInFuture = mTimeLeftInMillis;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
                final long millisPassed = millisInFuture - mTimeLeftInMillis;
                progress = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / millisInFuture);
                pb.setProgress(progress);
                pb2.setProgress(0);
                pb3.setProgress(0);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //Key: 60 sec
                if (millisInFuture == 480000) {
                    if (millisPassed <= 60000 || (millisPassed > 180000 && millisPassed <= 240000) || (millisPassed > 300000 && millisPassed <= 360000 || (millisPassed > 420000 && millisPassed <= 480000))) {
                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                        stepupimage.setAnimation(animation);
                        stage_timer2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        stage_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        pb3.setProgress(0);
                        stageTime = 60000;
                        Log.println( Log.VERBOSE,"CHECK","StageTime= "+stageTime);
                    } else if ((millisPassed > 60000 && millisPassed <= 180000)) {
                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                        stepdownimage.setAnimation(animation);
                        stage_timer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        stage_timer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        pb2.setProgress(0);
                        stageTime = 120000;
//                        stageDown((int) timeleft[5]);
                        Log.println( Log.VERBOSE,"CHECK","StageTime= "+stageTime);
                    } else if ((millisPassed > 240000 && millisPassed <= 300000) || (millisPassed > 360000 && millisPassed <= 420000)){
                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                        stepdownimage.setAnimation(animation);
                        stage_timer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        stage_timer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        pb2.setProgress(0);
//                        stageDown((int) timeleft[3]);
                        stageTime = 60000;
                    }

                }
```

This above is part of my countdown timer.

Now I want to pass *stageTime* from the above method to this method:

```
 private void stageUp(int value)
{
    mTimeLeftInMillis2 = value ;
    Log.println(Log.VERBOSE, "Check", "stage_time = "+mTimeLeftInMillis2);
    millisInFuture2 = mTimeLeftInMillis2;
   CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis2, 1000) {
       @Override
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "CHECK2", "stageup entered");
               mTimeLeftInMillis2 = millisUntilFinished;
               updateStageUpCount();
               long timestamp = millisInFuture2 - mTimeLeftInMillis2;
               progress2 = (int) (timestamp*100 /millisInFuture2);
               pb2.setProgress(progress2);

       }

       @Override
       public void onFinish() {

       }
   }.start();

}
```

This is another countdown timer but the value I'll pass would determine how long it would run.

Now when it's time for action the second method is never called:

```
  newbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startTimer();
            if(stageTime != -1){
                Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "CHECK","Entered stageUp method");
                stageUp(stageTime);
            }

        }
    });
```

But when I manually add a value for the *stageUp* method it works any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: I assume you declare this int variable stageTime as an instance variable. Can you log print what its value is after you run startTimer()? And do you see the log Entered stageUp method log message if you run a test?

Comment: the log message for stageUp never turns up. Only the ones in the startTimer() method are the ones that ever appear. As for the int variable stageTime I declared it as a global variable equal to -1.

Comment: Can you print a log right after the startTime() en before the if(stageTime != -1), where you also print the value stageTime? It might be -1 in your testcase or something else, which would explain the lack of logging of the stageUp method.

Comment: I placed the log message between startTime() and if(stageTime!= -1) it doesn't get printed